# SQL trigger fires but original value is not inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I am transitioning my database from storing datetimes in Pacific time into UTC, but will not be changing all of the code at the same time.

I am trying to write a trigger that will update times entered in either column and convert them and insert them into the other column.

Ex. If I insert a Pacific time in the OriginalTime column, it should convert the time to UTC and update the NewTime column with a time in UTC. Conversely, if I insert/update the value in NewTime, it should convert the time back to Pacific and put it in OriginalTime.

Am I looping things incorrectly or something?

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER tr_Calls_CreateDate ON Calls
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE
    @CallId INT,
    @CreateDate DATETIME,
    @CreateDateUTC DATETIME

--Create cursor
DECLARE CreateDate_Cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT CallId, CreateDate, CreateDateUTC FROM Inserted

OPEN CreateDate_Cursor;

-- Get First Row
FETCH NEXT FROM CreateDate_Cursor INTO @CallId, @CreateDate, @CreateDateUTC;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE ([CreateDate])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Calls
        SET CreateDateUTC = dbo.ConvertPacificTimeToUTC(@CreateDate)
        WHERE CallId = @CallId
    END

    IF UPDATE ([CreateDateUTC])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Calls
        SET CreateDate = dbo.ConvertUTCTimeToPacific(@CreateDateUTC)
        WHERE CallId = @CallId
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CreateDate_Cursor INTO @CallId, @CreateDate, @CreateDateUTC;
END

-- Free Up Cursor
CLOSE CreateDate_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE CreateDate_Cursor;
END
```

For some reason, my current trigger is entering the converted value correctly, but the insert that caused the trigger to fire seems to be failing.

If I insert a value:

```sql
INSERT INTO Calls (CreateDate)
VALUES (GETDATE()) -- getdate currently outputs in pacific time
```

I get the trigger result but not the inserted value:

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+
|   CreateDate    |      CreateDateUTC       |
+-----------------+--------------------------+
|       NULL      | 2013-01-24 20:27:13.510  |
+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: A cursor AND a trigger ... my eyes, my eyes... they burn.  I'd try to rewrite that with a single update and a case statement to leave it set based.

Comment: haha I've seen that sentiment a lot but not much to back it up. (not saying there isn't) Since this needs to fire off each time a record is added/modified, isn't a trigger appropriate? As far as the cursor/set debate, do you have any resources handy showing how to convert it over to a set-based model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On an insert `UPDATE(column)` is true for all columns. That is wh your second update writes a null into the CreateDate column.

So you need to create two triggers, One that deals with updates as in your code and one that deals with inserts. If only CreateDate is valued, CreateDateUTC is NULL and you can check for that.

Also, you should really not use a cursor for this. Use something like this instead:

```
UPDATE c SET
  CreateDate = ISNULL(CreateDate, dbo.ConvertUTCTimeToPacific(i.CreateDateUTC)),
  CreateDateUTC = ISNULL(CreateDateUTC, dbo.ConvertPacificTimeToUTC(i.CreateDate))
FROM dbo.Calls AS c
JOIN INSERTED AS i
ON i.CallId = c.CallId;
```

That is, for the insert trigger. For the UPDATE you can use something like this:

```
UPDATE c SET
  CreateDate = CASE WHEN UPDATE ([CreateDateUTC]) THEN CreateDate
                  ELSE dbo.ConvertUTCTimeToPacific(i.CreateDateUTC)
               END,
  CreateDateUTC = CASE WHEN UPDATE ([CreateDate]) THEN CreateDateUTC
                    ELSE dbo.ConvertPacificTimeToUTC(i.CreateDate)
                  END
FROM dbo.Calls AS c
JOIN INSERTED AS i
ON i.CallId = c.CallId;
```

This is all untested code, but it should work.

---

EDIT: See my longer comment below for why you really should wrap this `UPDATE` inside of an `IF` statement.

Comment: Hey, I think I meet you at red gate SQLInTheCity Seattle a few weeks ago.  If that was you, good presentation.  +1 on answer.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for the answer. The INSERT looks correct, but I have a question on the UPDATE. I think the logic is slightly backward but I didn't want to edit your post without discussion. I made a gist with the reversed logic and also a question on whether the CASE statements are required. Thanks for your input. https://gist.github.com/4629551

Comment: @RThomas, I did present there. Glad you liked it.

Comment: @jstim, you are right. I corrected the logic above. SQL Server does not actually write the new value during an update if it equals the old value, so you don't need to worry about that. However, it does make sense to wrap the entire `UPDATE` into an `IF` statement to execute the `UPDATE` only if one of the two columns actually changed. Without that SQL Server does still read every row and potentially even spend time in the function even if the end-result is that nothing gets changed. The `IF` syntax you suggested does not work in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation Sebastian. I'm going to test it all out right now.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, with a minor tweak everything's functional. I switched the case statement around in your answer to match the needed functionality. This gist shows the conditional as well. https://gist.github.com/f0cdbf041da6ba9e3a32